# Dificuldade variável local e global - PHP

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldade de entender como utilizar o valor de uma variável local em uma outra declaração:

Estou utilizando esse conceito no seguinte código :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["email_cad"])){
    //quero usar a var $email_cad
    $email_cad = $_GET["email_cad"];
    if(!empty($email_cad)){
        $sql = "SELECT email_cad FROM part_user WHERE email_cad = '$email_cad' ";
        }else {
            echo "Insira um email";
            return;
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($linha['email_cad'] == $email_cad ){        
                echo $email_cad;

             }else {
                echo "Email inválido !";
             }  
}

if(isset($_GET["senha_cad"])){
    $senha_cad = $_GET["senha_cad"];
    if(!empty($senha_cad)){
        //Aqui estou recebendo o erro onde $email_cad é indefinida
        $sql = "SELECT senha_cad FROM part_user WHERE email_cad = '$email_cad' ";
        }else {
            echo "Insira uma senha";
            return;
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($linha['senha_cad'] == $senha_cad ){        
                echo $senha_cad;
             }else {
                echo "Senha inválida !";
             }  
}
?>
```

Minha dúvida é, como usar a variável `$email_cad`com o mesmo valor em ambas as declarações ? Pois da forma que está, é retornado um erro : `Undefined index: email_cad`, para o uso na segunda declaração. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Por que não faz isso tudo em uma declaração? o `if(!empty(...)` é desnecessário, pois você usa o `isset`.

Comment: @zekk entendo que posso fazer de outras formas e obrigado pela atenção, no entanto a dúvida e o aprendizado, seria mesmo em como usar o valor da variável da 1º declaração na 2º.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode declarar a variável fora do `if`:

```
$email_cad = $_GET["email_cad"];

if(!empty($email_cad)){
    $sql = "SELECT email_cad FROM part_user WHERE email_cad = '$email_cad' ";
}else {
    echo "Insira um email";
    return;
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($linha['email_cad'] == $email_cad ){
    echo $email_cad;
}else {
    echo "Email inválido !";
} 
// Resto do código...
```